# Access Shared Resources from Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to access Shared Resources in a Tag Helper, but it doesn't return the value from the resource file even though I know it exists, only ResourceNotFound. I use IHtmlLocalizer to access shared resources in some of my views and it works fine so everything should be configured correctly.

**Tag Helper**:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("lc:buy-button", Attributes = "product", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class BuyButtonTagHelper : BaseTagHelper
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> _localizer;

    public BuyButtonTagHelper(AppHelper app, IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizer) : base(app)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        .........

        base.Process(context, output);
    }

    private string ProcessHtml(string html)
    {
        string result = html.Replace("{?productId?}", this.Product.ToString());
        result = result.Replace("{?subscribeText?}", _localizer["SubscribeButtonText"].Value);

        return result;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("product")]
    public int Product { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by installing the nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization**